# How do I retrieve gamepad button pressed status from navigator.getGamepads() in Rust wasm-bindgen?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

`web_sys::Navigator.getGamepads()` returns `Result<Array, JsValue>` whereas I was hoping for an array of `websys::Gamepad` objects.

How do I parse whether a gamepad button is pressed from the `wasm-bindgen::JsValue` result? Is there some way to convert it to a `web_sys::Gamepad` object?

Here's the setup for my attempt:

```rust
let window = web_sys::window().expect("global window does not exists");
let navigator = window.navigator();
let gamepads: Result<js_sys::Array, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> = navigator.get_gamepads();
for gp in gamepads.unwrap().iter() {
    // ... how to parse Gamepad.buttons from JsValue?
}
```

Reference: https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.Navigator.html#method.get_gamepads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert JsValue into Gamepad by using `wasm-bindgen::JsCast.dyn_into()`
https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/latest/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html#method.dyn_into

```rust
let window = web_sys::window().expect("global window does not exists");
let navigator = window.navigator();
let gamepads = navigator.get_gamepads().unwrap();
for js in gamepads.iter() {
    let gp: Gamepad = js.dyn_into().unwrap();  // <= convert here
    let buttons = gp.buttons();
    for index in 0..buttons.length() {
        let js: JsValue = index.into();
        console::log_2(&js, &(buttons.get(index))); 
    }
}
```